# how to set ontap for different tabbars flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 10 tab bars. For my TabBar() Widget, I have set the onTap(int) property to scroll the screen with a scrollController.animateto() method. But for each tab I want it to scroll to different places in my ListView and don't know how to do this. When tapping the tab 'Parks' for example, the scrollController scrolls the listview down to where I want it, but when I click back onto 'Markets' it doesn't take the screen back to its original position, and I don't know how to set the other tabs to different positions either. Thanks all.

```
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flex(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                  onTap: (int){
                      _scrollController.animateTo(320, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                  },
                  tabs: choices.map((Choice choice) {
                    return Tab(
                      text: choice.title,
                    );}).toList(),),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 11,
                  child: Container(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount: ItemsList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        String imgPath = ItemsList[index].image;
                        String namePath = ItemsList[index].name;
                        String descriptionPath = ItemsList[index].d;
                        return ItemCards(
                            itemDescription: descriptionPath,
                            itemName: namePath,
                            gridOutline: GridTile(
                              child: Image.network(imgPath),
                            ),
                            flatButton: myFlat(),
                        );},),),),],),],),
```

My Tabs are in their own class:

```
const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Markets'),
  const Choice(title: 'Parks'),
  const Choice(title: 'Restaurants'),
  const Choice(title: 'Schools'),
  const Choice(title: 'Shops'),
  const Choice(title: 'Gas'),
  const Choice(title: 'Parking'),
  const Choice(title: 'Clubs'),
  const Choice(title: 'Bars'),
  const Choice(title: 'Theatres'),

];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(choice.title, style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),),],),),);}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set diferent positions using the switch, i create a Function to return the animation to reduce code:

The function:

```
Future<void> _scrollControllerAnimation(double offset) {
  return _scrollController.animateTo(
    offset,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
  );
}
```

The switch inside onTap:

```
onTap: (int) {
  switch (int) {
    case 0:
      _scrollControllerAnimation(0);
      break;
    case 1:
      _scrollControllerAnimation(300);
      break;
    case 2:
      _scrollControllerAnimation(500);
      break;
    case 3:
      _scrollControllerAnimation(200);
      break;
    default:
      _scrollControllerAnimation(0);
  }
},
```

And then add the scroll position to the other tabs.